# Create a clone of an Exact Online company

Tags: exact-online

I am trying to create a clone of an Exact Online company to test new functionality (this is also helpful to GDPR regulations). I seem able to create a backup and download it, but there is no button to upload a backup created from another company.

What am I missing? There used to be a button to Upload a previously taken backup as shown in the manual:
[image: Upload backup]
and
[image: Available buttons]

But there is no button shown, I have all privileges:

[image: Available buttons]

Comment: Its called Restore. If that doesn't work, contact Exact.

Comment: @LPChip No, it is not called *Restore*... Upload is the step before restore.